A show from the early 70s about war and peace
I'm looking for a TV show. The best memory I have of the show is some scenes of the intro and its music. The intro shows fire burning documents of political nature or maybe confidential documents. Fire might have been used as a transition effect between scenes. The show was in color.
The subject might have been about geopolitics or world wars. Russia might have figured prominently in the show, and maybe few other countries (based on the costumes). The story might have been based on a novel. The novel might have been written by a non American prominent writer/politician/philosopher - my best guess is he's a Russian writer.
The show might have been produced by the BBC. I do not think it was produced by an American media company. The music of the intro sounded almost classical - sad and dreary. The show, even though I do not recall watching a single episode of, was about, I believe, war and peace. It was a 'serious' drama show.
I searched YouTube a few dozen different ways and found nothing close to what I remember.

The intro sounds like the documentary series The World at War. You might want to list some obvious candidates that you have eliminated from your search.

Thank you!
I found on you tube the intro of the documentary you linked. The music is exactly what I remember. So it turns out it wasn't a drama. Thanks again.

Based on the description of the introduction, I propose that this is the documentary series The World at War

The World at War (1973–74) is a 26-episode British television
  documentary series chronicling the events of the Second World War. At
  the time of its completion in 1973, it was, at a cost of £900,000,
  (inflation adjusted to around £7.5 million in 2016) the most expensive
  factual series ever made.1 It was produced by Jeremy Isaacs,
  narrated by Laurence Olivier and included music composed by Carl
  Davis. The book The World at War written by Mark Arnold-Forster to
  accompany the TV series was released in 1973.

First episode (intro starts at 1m:50s)
